# Error while converting data to xml. Entity uuml not defined

Tags: php, xml, utf-8

I need to convert data from database to xml.But 'ü' char dont printing.

This code  not working.

```
 $cins = $xml->createElement( 'cins', "ü" );
```

Error Image
[image]

Please find 'uuml' keyword this page https://www.w3.org/People/mimasa/test/xhtml/entities/entities-math-svg-nofpi.xhtml#lat1

But this is working

```
$cins = $xml->createElement( 'cins', "u" );
```

Working Image
[image]

How can I fix this problem?

```
<?php
session_start();
$yol = $_SESSION[ 'kok_dizin' ] . "DatabaseOperations/ConnectionOperations.php";
require_once( $yol );

$connect = new Connection();
$connect->BaglantiyiAc();
$arrayMakineler = array();
$getMakinelerSql = "select mac_id,makine_cinsi from envanter_listesi where makine_cinsi!='' and  makine_cinsi!='(BOŞ)'";
$queryResultMakineler = $connect->connectionKey->query( $getMakinelerSql, PDO::FETCH_BOTH );

if ( $queryResultMakineler->rowCount() > 0 ) {

    foreach ( $queryResultMakineler as $row ) {
        array_push( $arrayMakineler, $row );
    }
    $connect->BaglantiyiKapat();
}

header( "Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8" );

$xml = new DOMDocument( '1.0', 'UTF-8' );

$makineler = $xml->createElement( 'makine_cinsleri' );

for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $arrayMakineler ); $i++ ) {
    $mac_id = $arrayMakineler[ $i ][ "mac_id" ];
    $makine_cinsi = $arrayMakineler[ $i ][ "makine_cinsi" ];

    $makine = $xml->createElement( 'makine' );
    $id = $xml->createElement( 'id', $mac_id);
    $cins = $xml->createElement( 'cins', "ü" );

    $makine->appendChild( $id );
    $makine->appendChild( $cins );
    $makineler->appendChild( $makine );
}


$xml->appendChild( $makineler );

//$xml->save('makineler.xml');
echo $xml->saveHTML();

?>
```

Comment: If you save as XML rather than HTML does issue still occur? https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php Also does DB have entities, maybe storing UTF8 char is better option, if possible?

Comment: header( "Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8" );

$xml = new DOMDocument( '1.0', 'UTF-8' );already utf-8 right now

Comment: Not sure what you are showing there. The entity value is for places that UTF8 can be used, if you have UTF8 everywhere use the UTF8 character.

Answer (score 2):

`&uuml;` is not a valid XML entity. It is only valid in specific XML based formats like (X)HTML. You need to use an DTD that defines that entity or use the numeric entity `&#252;` or `&#xFC;`.

In your case you're saving the document as HTML and the serializer uses named entities. But you're creating/sending XML. You should use the `DOMDocument::saveXML()` method.

```
$document = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$element = $document->appendChild(
    $document->createElement('cins')
);
$element->textContent = "ü";

echo $document->saveHTML();
echo "\n"; 
echo $document->saveXML();
```

Output:

```
<cins>&uuml;</cins>

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<cins>&#xFC;</cins>
```

Even better - set the encoding on the created document. This makes the encoding for umlauts unnecessary.

```
$document = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$element = $document->appendChild(
    $document->createElement('cins')
);
$element->textContent = "ü";

echo $document->saveXML();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cins>ü</cins>
```

Comment: Data comes from database.I have data 'Düz Makine' named on makine_cinsi column.This is also a problem.I wrote to try the letter 'ü'.How can i solve this problem

Comment: Do not store entities in the database - but unicode strings. Make sure that the encoding of the database connection is UTF-8. The DOM methods expect UTF-8 strings.